# Can we undo suggestion to make [tr] be a synonym of [html-table]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I am one of those who from time to time enters into the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) page : ) It normally takes, literally, years to have one accepted.

Now I saw there is one suggestion that is a bit counterintuitive: [tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tr) to be a synonym of [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table).

[image]

As the excerpt of `tr` says:

> `tr` is a *nix utility for character-level alterations to a stream.
>   `tr///` is a Perl operator named after this utility. For the tag used
>   to build HTML tables, please use [html-table].

So could it be voted down to prevent mixing things that are not supposed to be?

Comment: I would just remove that tr tag. We don't need a tag for each binary under the sun...

Comment: Now you'll be on the hook to make sure that no one uses that tag for the HTML `tr` element ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, the suggestion got enough downvotes to get the synonym request rejected.